# Why would TypeScript evaluate property of an object referenced by one of it's keys to be Never?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the following simple example code that is assigning a value of type `any` to a property of an object referenced by a provided key, TypeScript is returning an error that suggests that the property is somehow `never`.  The code:

```js
type TypeAObject = {
  'first': string;
  'second': string;
  'third': number;
}

const assignKeyValue = (key: keyof TypeAObject, obj: TypeAObject, value: any) => {
  obj[key] = value; // Error: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}
```

This results in the following TypeScript error, seeming to suggest that `obj[key]` is `never`, even though `key` is explicitly `keyof TypeAObject`:

> Error: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.

I am running TypeScript 4.9.5.

This error can be seen at the following TypeScript playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEDyAjAVhAxsKBeKA3gFBRQDkAZgJYBOAzsGQFxQM1UB2A5gNwnl0sAew4ATZq2DtufUmWAALWuJYcArgFsUEGnwC+RIphEMoAQzp0qXDgGkIIAGpmANmuj4AFAGsHLXyBCFLDwyOhYwAA0UELoLHCQYRjY0QBuru4sZhwgAJR4AHyE-LFoANoBALp4UOluEPpAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current implementation the `obj[key]` is resolved as `string & number`. Since `string` and `number` have nothing in common, the intersection results in `never` (empty set).

The right thing to do would be to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) for the object, key and using these two you can determine the type of the value:

```
const assignKeyValue = <T extends TypeAObject, K extends keyof T>(key: K, obj: T, value: T[K]) => {
  obj[key] = value; // no error
}
```

Comment: That makes sense given what I'm seeing, but I guess I'm unclear on why it resolves as `string & number` instead of `string | number`, as would be the type of currentValue if I added a line `const currentValue = obj[key]`.  Could you add an explanation of why it's resolving as `string & number`?

Comment: You might want to mention why that intersection is happening: when you write to a property indexed by a *union* of key types, you have to pass the *intersection* of value types to be safe, see [ms/TS#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769).   (This is different from when you *read* from such a property, where you get the union.)

Comment: @BenZittlau jcalz already explained why

Comment: @jcalz not sure how you remember all of the relevant issues:D?